# How to find out what is a final resolution for the closed feature-request?

Tags: support

The use-case.

1. I find a useful question on the meta with the `feature-request` tag.
2. The question also have a tag `status-completed` or `status-declined`.
3. *"...Hmm, but why???"* or *"Cool! But how it was implemented?"*.

And then the quest begins:

1. I open the recent changes to the question.
2. Find the author of the change, that places the resolution tag.
3. Look through the answers and find the answer from this person.

Is there a more convenient way to find the final resolution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a more convenient way to find the final resolution?

No.

There is no formal process for documenting why a feature request was declined, or how it was completed.

Sometimes, the information can be found....

- in a comment posted by a SE employee
- in an answer posted by a SE employee
- in the top-voted answer, even if it's not by a SE employee. Often, this answer is highly upvoted and reflects some sort of community consensus
- in one of the other answers

sometimes, it is not present at all.

Comment: And how to find out who is employee and who is not?

Comment: @abyss most of them have a moderator diamond `♦` next to their name. A look in their profile will show whether they are community moderators or Stack Exchange employees. [Example](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9)

Comment: Does the diamond stay still, when the person retires from the moderation? Or it's not the case?

Comment: It goes away when a person is no longer an active moderator or employee.

Comment: SE should really get some bug-tracker then...

Comment: Meh, it's worked okay so far. There are so many requests that it isn't realistic to expect a response from the team to every one.